# Filter out boolean as non-integer?

Tags: python, integer, boolean

I have always wondered about the following code snippet:

```
import math
def func(n):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError('input is not an integer')
    return math.factorial(n)

print(func(True))
print(func(False))
```

I'm always surprised at the result because `True` and `False` actually work and are interpreted as the integers `1` and `0`. Therefore the factorial function produces the expected results `1` and `1` when using `True` and `False`. The behavior of those booleans is clearly [described in the python manual](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) and for the most part I can live with the fact that a boolean is a subtype of integer.

However, I was wondering: is there any clever way to wash away something like `True` as an actual parameter for the factorial function (or any other context which requires integers) in a way that it'll throw some kind of exception which the programmer can handle?

Comment: you shouldn't rely on strict type checking in python. If one want's to call a function with boolean, why not?

Comment: @Daniel I'm not exactly sure why it bothers me just a little bit. In this specific context it just feels dissatisfying to know that factorial works just fine with a boolean. I was wondering: why would you prefer to use strict type checking in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `bool` is a *subtype* of `int` and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) can walk through inheritance to pass `True` as an `int` type.

Use the more stricter `type`:

```
if type(n) is not int:
    raise TypeError('input is not an integer')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was completely blind because I was not aware of this little nuance regarding `type` and `isinstance` until a moment ago.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code seems to distinguish between boolean and integer parameters in functions. What am I missing?

```
import math
def func(n):
    if type(n) == type(True):
        print "This is a boolean parameter"
    else:
        print "This is not a boolean parameter"
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError('input is not an integer')
    return math.factorial(n)

print(func(True))
print(func(False))
print(func(1))
```